# Youtube API, AuthSub or ClientLogin?

Tags: php, api, youtube

So I'm kinda stumped on which authentication method I should be using. Basically, my app should be allowing others to upload to MY OWN Youtube account. From my understanding AuthSub allows the user to authenticate with their own YT account, and ClientLogin stores their userinfo to login.

So my question is, if I'm using ClientLogin and just make it login to my account, is it possible for them to get the password of my account or anything else other than uploading?